# Meaning of "How about her?"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I said

```
They had hardworking personalities. Also she was.
```

then she said

```
How about her?
```

Here, what does she mean by this? I am not a native English speaker but she is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the woman you are talking to is pointing at one of the girls, then she means

> What about that one?

If she's not pointing, then she might mean

> **How about her?**
>   *What (else) about her did you like?*
>   *Tell me more about what you liked about her*

or because you made the potential flirting gambit of

> especially the girl who looked like you

the woman you are speaking to might mean

> Tell me other things you liked about that girl *(other than that she looked like me because I'm interested in you, and I'm wondering if you're interested in me also, which I will try to figure out by seeing if I have those other characteristics that you are going to tell me you liked)*

it can depend on context and situation.

Comment: Fairly good answer. The point of the answer is that the meaning of this usage is contingent on the situation, and on personal intention of the speaker. The usage "How about her" is intentionally vague, so that the speaker can use many different responses, depending on how they think the conversation is evolving when the target responds. I.e.: 
original speaker: "How about her?" 
target: "Well, she has x."
orig speaker: can now respond in a large number of ways, due to the vagueness of "How about her"